# How Do I reset a List Loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have this program where characters deal damage to other characters using the Weapon object. So I instantiated two players and two enemies. Then pushed them into a players list and an enemies list. So each list has two objects. I set up the iterators and a for loop that should shuffle the list over every loop, so each attack is random. That way, a turn is made until I reach the end of both lists. Now I want to reset the for loop so that players will keep taking turns until both enemies or both players die and its game over. I tried using a while(true) loop and have the for loop be nested, but that just makes the program stop after the loop ends. How would I set the for loop to reset so that players and enemies keep attacking until game over? I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

```
int main()
{


srand(time(NULL));  

PlayerCharacter* p1 = new PlayerCharacter();
PlayerCharacter* p2 = new PlayerCharacter();
EnemyCharacter* e1 = new EnemyCharacter();
EnemyCharacter* e2 = new EnemyCharacter();

p1->printCharacter();
p2->printCharacter();
e1->printCharacter();
e2->printCharacter();


string enemyTarget, playerTarget;

list<Character*> players;
list<Character*> enemies;

players.push_back(p1);
players.push_back(p2);
enemies.push_back(e1);
enemies.push_back(e2);


list<Character*>::iterator PinsertIt = players.begin();
list<Character*>::iterator EinsertIt = enemies.begin();


while (!p1->dead && !p2->dead && !e1->dead && !e2->dead)
{

    if (PinsertIt == players.end()) {
        PinsertIt = players.begin();
    }
    if (EinsertIt != enemies.end()) {
        EinsertIt = enemies.begin();
    }


    for (; PinsertIt != players.end() && EinsertIt != enemies.end(); ++PinsertIt, ++EinsertIt)
    {

        listShuffle(players);
        listShuffle(enemies);

        if (*PinsertIt == p1)
        {
            if (!p1->dead)
            {
                cout << "Player One. Choose your Target (1 or 2)" << endl;
                cin >> playerTarget;
                playerAttack(e1, e2, p1->currentWeapon, playerTarget);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << p1->firstName << " " << p1->lastName << " is dead. Skip turn" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (*PinsertIt == p2)
        {
            if (!p2->dead)
            {
                cout << "Player Two. Choose your Target (1 or 2)" << endl;
                cin >> playerTarget;
                playerAttack(e1, e2, p2->currentWeapon, playerTarget);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << p2->firstName << " " << p2->lastName << " is dead. Skip turn" << endl;
            }
        }


        if (*EinsertIt == e1)
        {

            if (!e1->dead)
            {
                cout << "Enemy One ";
                enemyAttack(p1, p2, e1->currentWeapon);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << e1->firstName << " " << e1->lastName << " is dead. Skip turn" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (*EinsertIt == e2)
        {
            if (!e2->dead)
            {
                cout << "Enemy Two ";
                enemyAttack(p1, p2, e2->currentWeapon);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << e2->firstName << " " << e2->lastName << " is dead. Skip turn" << endl;
            }
        }



        if (p1->dead && p2->dead)
        {
            cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
        }
        else if (e1->dead && e2->dead)

        {
            cout << "You Win!" << endl;
        }


    }
    PinsertIt++;
    EinsertIt++;

}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use pointers and `new`.  We will need a [MCVE].

Comment: why not? It's a list of character pointers. I just want to know how to reset a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop end condition to check either all players are dead or all enemies are dead. In your loop, if `PinsertIt` or `EinsertIt` hit the end of list, reset it back to begin.

```
while (!isAllPlayersDead() && !isAllEnemiesDead()) {
    if (PinsertIt == players.end()) {
        PinsertIt = players.begin();
    }
    if (EinsertIt != enemies.end()) {
        EinsertIt = enemies.begin();
    }

    doSomeThingWithYourPlayersAndEnemies();

    PinsertIt++;
    EinsertIt++;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my code with your suggestion, but after the the for loop ends. I get an error window saying 'iterator not incrementable'

Comment: If you use for loop, remove `PinsertIt++;` and `EinsertIt++;` at the end of your code. Becasue the for loop has already  increased 2 iterators for you, and when it hit end() , it cannot increase any more

Comment: And your implements of `isAllPalyerDead()` and `isAllEnemiesDead()` are wrong. Check [my explain](https://ideone.com/vflrKZ) and [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more details. Also, you should put complex condition in seperate function to incresase code readability and maintainability